# Tracking changes in JSON files

Tags: json, testing

One of the resources my app uses is data in two JSON files that are pulled from a third party and that are constantly updated with fresh content.
Each of these files have a specific structure that doesn't change.
However, sometimes the third party creates structural changes that may mess with my app.

My question is: how can I monitor their structure so I can detect changes as they occur?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this reason you can use [json schema](http://json-schema.org/) and validate the files agains it. If they have the schema than you're, good just need to validate. If not than you have to do it based on a correct json. There are online [generators](http://jsonschema.net/#/) for that.